# Attach hidden information to txt file in c#

Tags: c#

I'm building a simple cryptography application which be able to encrypt and decrypt a text inside any given txt file. The decryption proccess should determine which encryption type was used on the text, and with that type decrypt the specified txt files text.
My question is, is there any way to attach a hidden information to a txt file which I will be able to read in the decryption proccess.
Edit:
What I mean by hidden, is that the user will not be able to see it in any way. It also should not reflect on the encrypted text.

Comment: No, you can't hide information in a file. I am not even sure what that means. Please define hidden *something* in a file.

Comment: If you store something in a text file it's not hidden.

Comment: You can encrypt the hidden info as well. Only you know how to decrypt it. ;)

Comment: Look at [ADS](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=NTFS+Alternate+Data+Streams) this can "hide" some info. But power user can find it without problem.

Comment: Most apps like this use a database to store this but as mentioned eventually someone can work it out.

Comment: sure, you can reserve the first x bits for header information and the rest for the content. But the information will not be hidden

Comment: But... If it is encrypted why would you want to hide it??

Comment: It is also not going to work on "any given text file" if you are depending on header data or "hidden" data unless you are the only one generating the files (which would NOT be "any given text file").

Comment: Like `digital invisible binary ink`?

Comment: @Ian And how would I use it to determine which encryption was used to encrypt the file?

Comment: @EvgenyGoldin what I mean is, *you* encrypt it with the way *you* want it. You *determine* it. You do not try to *figure out* how it is encrypted because *you* made it. ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah, obviously.. I thought more of something like attributes? Or metadata?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to attach a hidden information to a txt file which I will be able to read in the decryption proccess. Edit: What I mean by hidden, is that the user will not be able to see it in any way

No, it is not possible. A text file is, by definition, a simple stream of bytes which represent an encoding of some text. All of the bytes are accessible to the user, decoded by whatever program they use to view the file (which could be something as simple as a hex-dump utility).

That said, some text encodings (including Unicode) include characters that are not themselves displayed, but which are normally used to affect rendering, text layout, character composition, etc. Depending on your specific goals, I suppose you could embed such characters strategically in the text of your file such that they are detectable by your algorithm and can be interpreted to recover information in the file.

But if your program can get at the data, so can anyone else's. Any program that is designed, for example, to show characters that are normally not displayed will show the data. Likewise, a program that just displays the bytes of the file. In such scenarios, a user may well note the extraneous character data and determine that the file contains data besides the text that is normally the only thing visible when the file is loaded by traditional text-viewing tools.

I guess it's worth pointing out that *some* file systems (including NTFS) support multiple streams of data for a file. In such environments, you could put the non-text data in an alternate stream. Conventional tools wouldn't show that data. But a) the alternate stream is still visible to any user that knows to look for it, and b) such streams are practically never preserved when some file's data is moved elsewhere (e.g. copied over a network). It's a very fragile solution that could easily lead to encrypted files being completely unrecoverable.

> It also should not reflect on the encrypted text.

I don't have any idea what you mean here. "Reflect" how?